# assign program to button GUI interface

Tags: c#, user-interface, gtk

i want to take my program which i have built and assign it to run when the onrunapplication button in my GUI interface is clicked:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{   
public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    Build ();
}

protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
{
    Application.Quit ();
    a.RetVal = true;
}

protected void OnExitbuttonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Quit();
}

protected void OnRunapplicationClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ???
}
}
```

Here's the beginning of my program that i want to run:

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace namelookup
{
    class MainClass
    {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Process` class to run another executable.  In the simple case it can just be `Process.Start("MyProgram.exe");`  There are many options in how you configure the process through various properties of both the returned `Process` object, as well as the `ProcessStartInfo` class which you probably want to look into.

Another option would be to not compile your other program as an executable at all; you could compile it as a class library and then have your UI add a reference to that library so it could just call the code directly.